# Performing CRUD operations in html5 (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, crud

I am doing a small app using html5 in Intel xdk and I want to connect to Microsoft SQL Server and perform CRUD operations. Is there a framework out there that I can use? I need some recommendations and advice please. I am using the bootstrap template in Intel xdk. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use HTML to get data from a database as it's just a markup language, there is far more to it. I think you need to do a bit more research on how this can be done. Far too many options and too broad to fit into an answer on SO.

somewhere to start:
[CRUD operation using html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830840/crud-operation-using-html5)